# Split a sentence/string in to words using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a sentece/H1 and I need this to split so that it would look like below

Original state

```
<h1>This is the heading </h1>
```

after

```
<h1>This <br> 
is <br> 
the <br> 
heading </h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("h1").html( $("h1").text().replace(/ /g,"<br>"))​
```

Comment: David Thomas, thanks. I've answered from mobile version and couldn't mark it like source code.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
$('h1').each(
    function(){
        var that = $(this),
            newText = that.text().replace(/\W/g,'<br />');
        that.html(newText);
    });
```

- [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uJZpB/).

References:

- jQuery references:

  - [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- JavaScript references:

  - [`regular expressions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
  - [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('h1').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).html().replace(/^\s*(.*?)\s*$/,'$1');
    // this trims the string
    $(this).html(txt.split(/\s+/).join(' <br/>')+' ');
    // this splits the character groups (not containing spaces)
    // and joins them by a br tag, then adds an extra space at the end.
});
```

Alternative, and a shorter version (thanks to [VisioN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1249581/vision)) :

```
$('h1').each(function() {
    $(this).html($.trim($(this).html()).split(/\s+/).join(' <br/>')+' ');
});
```

Comment: No need in RegExp trimming. `$.trim()` does the job.

Comment: ahhh!!! I saw the split function and was trying to figure out how to use it didn't realise I can actually split using the space!!!

Comment: just an alternative approach…

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var h = $('h1').text().split(' ').join('<br>'); 
$('h1').html(h);
```